# Showing array which is updating onPress everytime in render - ReactNative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have 2 classes and in one class upon pressing on a `TouchableOpacity` i'm adding some id's to an array.

1st class - (AddToCard )

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.addtogroupcard} onPress={() => addToArray(reviewer.id)}>
  <Icon name="ios-add-circle-outline" style={styles.friendaddicon}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

2nd class

```
class AddMem extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

            selectedMembers: []

        }
    }


    addToArray(id) {

        this.state.selectedMembers.push(id)
        console.log("selectedMembers", this.state.selectedMembers);

    }

    render() {

         return (

            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'whitesmoke', padding: 10}}>

                  <AddToCard reviewer={reviewer} key={reviewer.id} addToArray={this.addToArray.bind(this)}/>
             ////this is where i want to display my array data



            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

How is it possible to show these array data without updating the array all over again, but only the new data added to the array.

My approach was like this but it doesn't work

```
{this.state.selectedMembers.map(selectedMember => selectedMember)}
```

Comment: Anytime you update your state your render component runs again

Comment: @JasonMcFarlane my approach was like this {this.state.selectedMembers.map(selectedMember => selectedMember)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First Problem is:

`this.state.selectedMembers.push(id)`

Don't mutate the state directly.
Use:

```
const newArray = [ ...this.state.selectedMembers, id ];
this.setState({ selectedMembers: newArray });
```

Build the new Array and store it in the newArray variable.
Then mutate your state via `setState`.

2) When I understand you right you want to show only the new added id's, right?

You could separate this data and give the id's you already got as prop
`members={[ /* member ids*/ ]}`

And then render all stuff:

```
render() {

     return (

        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'whitesmoke', padding: 10}}>

              <AddToCard reviewer={reviewer} key={reviewer.id} addToArray={this.addToArray.bind(this)}/>
              {
                  this.props.members.map(id => (
                      <Text key={id}>{id}</Text>
                  ))
              }
              {
                  this.state.selectedMembers.map(id => (
                      <Text key={id}>{id}</Text>
                  ))
              }



        </View>
    );
}
```